# Maintain item position after editing a row in a list... should I even try?

Tags: asp.net, listview, user-interface

I am manually binding an ASP.NET ListView to an array of objects sorted alphabetically by name. After editing an item, the DataSource is set again and DataBind is called. If the name changed, the item you just edited may have moved, potentially to another page even.

For example; you just renamed Hot Dog to Sausage, so Sausage moved after ItemUpdating completes.

```
--- OLD LIST ---   --- NEW LIST ---
    Hamburger          Hamburger
    Hot Dog______      Pizza
    Pizza        |_____Sausage
```

**Is this behavior you would expect from a form? When you edit a row, should you expect to see that row after saving it? Should it be in the exact same position? Should I display *only* the record you just edited after saving?**

As for the technical side of maintaining the previous order after saving, and potentially *changing* the order;

I know *why* this is happening. I'm looking for ideas of avoiding it.

I'm thinking about dropping both combining the controls of EditItemTemplate into ItemTemplate and setting visibility on read-only / editable controls based on the ListView EditIndex.

This seems feasible but I'm wondering if you fine folks have any other ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior that you are seeing here is the typical desired output as once you make the change the information is properly sorted.  If you have a need to keep the old structure you are most likely going to have to go a route similar to what you mentioned in your post.

However, I would take a second and see if this is really what your users are going to want, I could see this getting really confusing after a large number of edits.

Comment: Is re-sorting after edit typical behavior for lists of data? I'm trying to recall any web apps where I've even needed to edit a row that would get sorted away from it's original location, but I'm failing to do so at the moment.

Comment: Yes, I have used several web-based management tools that all behave in this fashion.  The list is re-sorted after each edit.  The only variation seems to be whether you stay where you were in the list, or follow the record to the new location.  This is especially relevant when paging comes into play... and THAT is dependent on your users' requirements.

Comment: Here is a perfect example - my online banking scheduled payments are sorted by date to be paid.  I can change the date on the first item to a later date and it might disappear off the list.  This is the expected behavior as it is a view of what is going to be paid out for a given period of time.

Answer (score 1):

When I have my users work with data sets in `GridView`s, I always order my data by the database ID to make sure that each data item's position stays the same. Without knowing what your data source looks like, it's hard to say if you could avoid or alter the re-sort.

However, (***this is pure speculation since I don't know what kind of data you're working with***) if you saved your original data source in the session (I'm assuming that you're going back to the database and grabbing the data after submit), and it has some sort of ordered identifier, then you could do something like:

```
void ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    List<MyClass> foodDataSource = Session["dataSource"];
    ListItem editedFoodItem = foodListView.Items[e.ItemIndex];

    MyFood newFood = new MyFood(
        ((HiddenField)editedFoodItem.FindControl("foodId")).Value,
        ((Label)editedFoodItem.FindControl("foodName")).Text
    );

    foodDataSource.Where(k => k.foodId == newFood.foodId).foodName = newFood.foodName;

    // I'm guessing that you'll save somewhere in here,
    // rather than do an update-once-style commit to the database when the user clicks a save button.

    foodListView.DataSource = foodDataSource;
    foodListView.DataBind();
}
```

This assumes that you've hard-coded your `ItemTemplate` to include specific `WebControls`/`HtmlControls`. It's clunky, and this code needs to be refactored to quarantine nasty code like the `FindControl` calls within a separate function, but this is pretty close to what I do when my users update data in a `GridView` and then save their changes off to the database.

**Alternatively**, you could keep your current save methods the same, and just add something like:

```
void ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    ListItem editedFoodItem = foodListView.Items[e.ItemIndex];
    Label foodNameLabel = ((Label)editedFoodItem.FindControl("foodName"));

    foodNameLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;

    // Saving in here, somewhere.

    // I'm not totally positive that DisplayIndex is the correct property here.
    foodListView.Items.Where(k => k.DisplayIndex != e.ItemIndex).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
}
```

I'm not sure if your users would understand the UI cue, or if it'd help them if it faded out (which would make your life more complicated, of course), but I think this is less clunky than the above option as long as you're saving the changes to the database after every edit.

Answer (score 0):

It some cases I could see a need for not resorting the list and leaving the item where it's at. While us programmers understand what happened, an average user may think their item got deleted.

I've put together a sample website demonstrating this behavior. It's actually pretty simple to achieve, and I'm sure you can adapt my method for your project.

In a nut shell, every time the grid is bound, I order the list of data by the user's choice (or the default sort), but right before binding it to the grid, I check if the order should be preserved, in which case, I extract the last sequence number out of the DataKeyArray of the grid and associate those sequence numbers to their respective items. In the case where they didn't want to preserve order, I simply associate an incremental sequence number to each item in the sorted list. Then I simply sort by sequence number.

Take a look at the [project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/48001473/Stack%20Overflow%20Files/PersistantGridView.zip), and I think it will make more sense.